# How to get an object or instance from C# sealed class

Tags: c#

As the pictures below shows, in debug mode, we can see

```
var current = ProjectTree.SelectedItem.Tag
```

And the value of current is `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup`, the type of current is `object {Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup}`, while its type is `object`.

[image: Code]

[image: Output in debug mode]

Now my question is, what is the meaning of value and type here? What is the meaning of the bracket {}?

If I want to create a new instance of `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup`, which in debug mode will show the type of it is
`object {Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup}`, the value of it is `{Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup}`.

May I ask, how do I achieve this? I can't use the following due to an error:

```
PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup();
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9aZ.png)

This is how `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup` looks like, it is a sealed class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
namespace Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Group containing Plc system blocks & Plc system block groups
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public sealed class PlcSystemBlockGroup : IEngineeringObject, IEngineeringCompositionOrObject, IEngineeringInstance, IInternalObjectAccess, IInternalInstanceAccess, IInternalBaseAccess, IEquatable<object>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Composition of Plc system blocks
        public PlcBlockComposition Blocks { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Composition of Plc system block groups
        public PlcSystemBlockGroupComposition Groups { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     EOM parent of this object
        public IEngineeringObject Parent { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The name of the Plc system block group
        public string Name { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Determines whether the specified System.Object is equal to this instance.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   obj:
        //     The System.Object to compare with this instance.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the specified System.Object is equal to this instance; otherwise, false.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public override bool Equals(object obj);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a list of attributes for the given names.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   names:
        //     The names of the attributes to get.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A list of the attributes for the given names with nulls for names not found.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public IList<object> GetAttributes(IEnumerable<string> names);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a hash code for this instance.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A hash code for this instance, suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data
        //     structures like a hash table.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public override int GetHashCode();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sets a list of values for the given attributes.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   attributes:
        //     The attributes value list.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public void SetAttributes(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> attributes);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a System.String that represents the current System.Object.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A System.String that represents the current System.Object.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public override string ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Several people helped you out with your question. We're any of the answers of use to you? It's been 10 days since you asked the questions. I would expect that if it was worth asking the question, it would be at least worth commenting on one or more of the answers

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting, it works for me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Then you can accept and/or update the answer. That way, the next person to find your question will know what worke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one question in this question.

First: In the debugger display, you have:

| Name | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| current | {Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup} | object {Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup} |

What that means (starting on the outsides) is that the type of the variable `current` is object.  However, the `current` variable currently references an object of type `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup`.  The `Value` is obtained by calling `.ToString` on whatever the object is.  That method is defined as a virtual method on the `object` class, so it's available on *all* objects.  Classes can override that method and return any string that they'd like.  The `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup` class does not override that method, so it gets the version implement on `System.Object`.  The only thing that type knows about instances of itself is its type, so `System.Object.ToString` returns the type name.

The little triangular caret to the left of `current` can be clicked.  When you do that, you will see all the public properties of the `PlcBlockSystemGroup` that `current` refers to.

I do not know why the code you show:

```
PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup();
```

does not work (in your words: *"due to an error"*).  The code that you show (which includes the definition of the `PlcSystemBlockGroup` class) doesn't include a constructor.  That means that the compiler will furnish a default constructor (that initializes all fields to their default value).  That's as good as any other constructor, so that code should compile.

As @Serge has pointed out, `sealed` has nothing to do with this.  As he says, all `sealed` does is prevent any other class from inheriting from `PlcBlockSystemGroup`

The class is marked with the `SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute`.  That affects its behavior in partial and full-trust situations.  **What is the error you are seeing?**  Is it a compile time error or a run-time error.  What does the Siemens documentation say.  It's been a ***very*** long time since I dealt with a Siemens PLC, but if I remember correctly, they had terse but complete documentation.

**Update after OP Showed the "Error"**

IDE0059 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0059) isn't an error or even a compiler warning. It's a "style" warning from the editor.

The editor has a simple program flow analysis capability (for example, it can sense some instances of dead code). In this case, it's saying that you are assigning a reference to `current`, and, before you consume that value, you are reassigning a new value. You don't show enough code for me to tell you more, but the example in the link is very clear:

```
int v = Compute(); // IDE0059: value written to 'v' is never read, so assignment to 'v' is unnecessary.
v = Compute2();
```

That's why the suggestion is to use the *discard* operator (`_`); you aren't using the result of the call, you might as well be explicit in your intention to not use it.

I hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I have updated the error in the question.

PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup();

Comment: @james_66: I've updated my answer after your edit

Comment: @James_66: did any of this help? Did any of it answer your question? Remember the update and accept buttons

Comment: Hi I am still trying, sorry for keep you waiting, I will come back as soon as possible

Comment: Yes it works for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Then you can accept and/or update the answer. That way, the next person to find your question will know what worked

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow, does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it, but you can create the new class instance without any problem.

Sometimes  the sealed modifier is used on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This allow classes to derive from this class but prevents them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties.

and I can see this in your code

```
var current = ProjectTree.SelectedItem.Tag;

//and 

PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup();
```

How you can explain this?

Comment: This would be useful if the question was simple enough, but if you look at the posted code, the class doesn't have a public constructor. The question is not what `sealed` is, but rather how to instantiate the posted class (which the OP probably doesn't really want, but lacks knowledge to determine that)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am sorry but you are wrong.  There is always a default contstructor and you don't need to create another one.  If you add another constractor it will replace a default one.

Comment: I remember default constructors being shown on the (semi)decompiled code view, is that not the case? Otherwise, what error could the OP have?

Comment: A class can 1) declare a default constructor (and possibly other constructors) -> then it gets a default constructor (obviously), 2) not declare any constructors -> then the compiler will gin up a default constructor, 3) declare non-default constructor(s) but no default constructor -> in that case, the class will have no default constructor, or 4) declare a `private` default constructor (and possibly other private constructors) -> generally, in this case, it will also create a static factory method (named, perhaps, `Create`) since class instances cannot be constructed in the normal fashion

Comment: var current = ProjectTree.SelectedItem.Tag; is the original code.

I want to use PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup(); to achieve the same function.  But I got error, please find the error in the third picture of the question

Comment: @james_66 And what is the error?

Comment: unneccessay assignment of a value to 'current', please find detailed information in the picture

Answer (score -2):

The object { typeName } syntax indicate that the object is boxed, that is to sya

- ProjectTree.SelectedItem.Tag has type object
- Tag contained a PlcSystemBlockGroup
- you can cast it to unbox it:

  var current = (PlcSystemBlockGroup)ProjectTree.SelectedItem.Tag

As to why you can't create an instance, what's the error?

```
If I use PlcSystemBlockGroup current = new PlcSystemBlockGroup(); there is an error
```

Comment: Nope, the `{typeName}` syntax has **nothing** to do with boxing.  It means the type did not override `.ToString`

Comment: unneccessay assignment of a value to 'current', please find detailed information in the picture –

Comment: I accept the ToString point is technically correct, although in practice the most common reason to see that in the VS debugger is a cast is needed (shouldn't have said boxed, it's not a value type).

Comment: @ian: close by not quite. The `{typename}` syntax in the **Type** column indicates that that is the type of the object being examined. For example, in this case, it says `object {Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup}`. That says that the _variable_ `current` is of type object. But, the object to which that variable refers is of type `Siemens.Engineering.SW.Blocks.PlcBlockSystemGroup` (remember that a variable typed `object` can refer to anything, since _everything is an object_)